# Official instructions for 2018 LEGO employee Christmas gift 4002018?

Tags: instructions

The 2018 LEGO employee-exclusive Christmas gift 4002018 has been revealed to the masses from [various](https://i.redd.it/6pqoqfu8qm321.png) [sources](https://candidbricks.com/2018/12/11/2018-lego-employee-gift-lego-4002018-revealed/), by the people who have received them.

[image]

I could probably reverse engineer most of the set from image, but are the official instructions available anywhere?

Comment: I would suggest to wait a little. I'm sure instructions will be available, but the set is still very new, so it may take a while until people can upload either scanned or recreated instructions. It's certainly a nice set!

Comment: Did you got the set yourself or just curious?

Comment: @AnkitSharma Not yet

Comment: @AlexanderO'Mara so you are a Lego employee?

Comment: @AnkitSharma No, I'm not a LEGO  employee.

Comment: @AlexanderO'Mara updated answer

Answer (score 4, accepted):

BZPower has done [a live stream build of the set](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=dwNugW8lg1E). It's not exactly the instructions, but you can follow along with the video to learn how it's built.

[image]

Answer (score 10):

As TheBrickBlogger said, you need to wait:

[image]

Even contacted their customer support and the reply was:

> I don't think those are every available publicly
>
> Not unless you are an employee

And after insisting repeatedly, answer from seniors was:

> So they confirmed they would not be available. Sorry!
>
> ---

**Update:** [rebrickable](https://rebrickable.com/sets/4002018-1/employee-christmas-gift-2018/#parts) have full detail of all individual pieces (281) and video demo too.

Comment: Given that this is intended for employees only, it shouldn't be surprising that instructions, if any were made, would not be available publicly, nor is TLG obligated to publish them, so I wouldn't bother waiting. I've received a bag of bricks that build a [sculpture](https://novalistic.com/stuff/lego/reviews/6238721) that's only ever been given out in certain parts of Asia, and instructions for that aren't available online either, nor would I be comfortable publishing scans of the instructions without TLG's written permission (even if I'm well within my legal rights as a consumer to do so).

Answer (score 2):

I found a couple of  speed-build of the set on Youtube, that quickly show how some of the unclear parts are built.

[All New Bricks](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=BhoBqLat_C0)

[Sariel's LEGO® Workshop](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=THa9xVKfCVE)

Comment: As great as both of these channels are, what I don't understand is why TLG sent them review copies of a set that was never intended for general availability in the first place (and is, as described, an employee exclusive). Is it because they know the employee-given copies will just get gifted or resold and change hands in general and decided they might as well let everyone see them built?

Comment: @LegoSonicBoy these were not sent out with the intention to be review copies. Along with LEGO employees, this year, LEGO Ambassadors also received the set as a Christmas gift. Some of these Ambassadors who run YouTube channels or blogs choose to publish reviews or speed-builds of the set. This may or may not have been a good idea, as this set is not available to the general public. Previously, Ambassadors received a regular small to medium set for Christmas as a thank you for their contributions.

Comment: @TheBrickBlogger: Thanks for the clarification. Sounds like it's not quite exclusive to just employees after all. But I'd think LEGO Ambassadors were up there with them anyway.

Answer (score 2):

I found this video showing the building instruction booklet page by page

[[戴樂高] 2018- LEGO 4002018 INSTRUCTION 組裝圖](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=VnChga28SjU)